Could space habitats have large transparent roofs?
This is a question I have regarding the design of space habitats. Basically, a lot of the designs I've seen end up having transparent roofs that are open to space, like this:

Or this (technically a floor):

And many other examples like these.
My question is would large open windows to space like this be viable? My gut says that there would be severe problems with radiation shielding, but I'm not sure. Are designs like these viable?
Thanks!

You could fill your windows with water I suppose though there'd be a tradeoff with light transmission, radiation absorption and the use of a valuable resource

@user55819 yep storing it in the windows could be a double win but you wouldn't be able to use it or your radiation shielding would disappear, at best it would only be an emergency reserve

You could always simulate it with cameras and screens showing the outside. Additionally, you could play the classic prank that a asteroid is going to crash into the place.

Water is pretty good at blocking radiation.  So, if the transparent roof were two panes of glass with water between it would help with that.  So long as you could keep the water clean and not frozen.

Assuming 1 bar and 1g one big issue would be the internal pressure ~10 tonnes/ sqm pushing out (greater than the weight of a adult elephant)

@user55819 The Earth's magnetic field is overrated as radiation protection in the popular literature. It periodically disappears, and the effect on earthly life has been minimal.

Many of these artistic works are old - this changes a number of assumptions made by the people commissioning the work and the artist/s themselves in terms of what is possible, and what risks matter. Also relevant is that they are visually striking - other more sensible designs with short sight lines and smaller windows make for rather more forgettable art, so are copied and remembered less.
The big spinning designs have a myriad of engineering issues, so hand waving radiation shielding is a quite minor additional detail.
In the case of the second illustration, it is an O'niell cylinder which orbit end on to the sun (so cylinder cap is the bit getting solar radiation), with the angled reflectors bouncing light in but allowing harder radiation to pass through, with a substantial atmosphere depth adding a layer of shielding akin to earth. It is however notable that it appears the updated 2007 design deletes the windows because of the radiation challenges.

If I may venture a guess then metal or (opaque) composite materials (and if I may venture another guess: metal coated!) would be stronger than glass which is a big deal. I don't suppose that transparent plastic would be long-lived enough (the radiation and probably the oxygen makes it brittle), so it must be glass.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica - I would expect anybody doing actual materials analysis for something like this to also decide 'one asteroid and everybody dies' design is not so great either and add some internal walls, also solving some stability issues with the various fluids sloshing around. Also would expect thermal expansion issues in designs with big windows, especially with compound curves. .

I wondered about thermal expansion as well but there are (of course) glasses which don't expand much, which may actually be an advantage to other materials. (Or an incompatibility -- one would probably strive to align expansion coefficients among involved materials!).

They could have, but the odds are that such windows will be relatively rare features reserved for, for example, an observation deck, as opposed to for letting in sunlight to grow plants.
Since this question is about viability, let's start by considering the most economically viable space settlement.
Al Globus made a pretty good case that the most economically viable space settlement should be built in a low equatorial earth orbit because then it would be close to Earth and relatively well shielded from space radiation by Earth's magnetic field. Inside such a habitat, we will need to create a 24-hour day-night cycle. Windows in a rotating habitat located in low earth orbit are not going to do that.
An approach that might make more sense would be to place solar panels on the outside of the habitat and use them to power LEDs on the inside of the habitat. I do recall a presenter at a conference that I attended some time ago saying that you can deliver more useful light to plants with solar panels and LEDs than you can by placing them in direct sunlight - even after factoring in the energy conversion losses.
For people (who do appreciate windows) a possible alternative might be to install large displays that create the illusion of a large window. At the rate we are progressing with developing display technology, by the time we build a space station the view we experience from an artificial window might very well be better than glass.
Another alternative to real windows might be to use advanced augmented reality headsets that simply render windows with beautiful views in the wearer's field of vision.
Other requirements influence the hull design for a space station. Good strength-to-weigh is important if you want to spin the station to create artificial gravity. The hull should help protect its occupants from meteorites and space debris (see Whipple shielding). Finally, there may be a need to provide some additional radiation shielding beyond what the Earth's magnetic field provides naturally. These requirements are not particularly compatible with a desire to include large transparent windows.
Conclusion
The primary reasons for large windows are: a) to provide "light food" for plants, and b) so that humans can see outside. Both of these requirements can be satisfied in other, potentially better, ways. Other requirements include the need for impact resistance, radiation shielding, and high specific strength. When considering all of the requirements together, large windows made from a transparent material will be far from ideal from an architectural or engineering perspective. For the time being - at least until our technology becomes a lot more advanced - every design choice will need to be pretty optimal for a space habitat to be viable.

I love the idea of a SciFi where everyone constantly wears AR glasses despite many obvious downsides and the protagonist even says at one point, "I do suppose this would be much easier without the goggles, but... no". And then partway into the story the viewers finally learn why: All of the large windows with beautiful scenery and even the sky itself are actually just blank white surfaces with thick black frames and distinctive dot patterns identifying them.

Good systemic analysis.

First of all, is radiation really an issue?
I think it's a pretty safe bet to say that cancer will be "cured" within the next 50-100 years, or at absolute minimum, reach a point where handling it is nothing more than an over-the-counter pill or something similar. More optimistically, we might be able to simply genetically modify people to simply be more adapted to life in space and be nearly unaffected by radiation.
Basically, by the time we are considering constructing megastructures such as these, the issue of radiation will have become significantly less of an issue.
Beyond that though, there is no reason we can't construct radiation shielding which is only translucent specific parts of the electromagnetic spectrum. For example, sunglasses are commonly already designed to not let UV light through or the door of a microwave is designed to let you look through it while still blocking the high-powered microwave radiation.
The materials science of of a material that's supposed to be transparent to human vision (and perhaps let through some UV for plants too) while being opaque to all other space radiation would be tricky and possibly expensive, but not impossible.

Not all sources of ionizing radiation is electromagnetic. Protons produce muons (which are what we get dosed with when we fly too often), neutrons, etc. I'm not sure that an unsupported "Science fiction will become science fact, everything will be OK" makes for a good Stack Exchange answer.

@uhoh I think the scope of this question (O'Niel cylinders) is adjacent to science fiction. While we can't predict the future, I think that considering the possibilities is a valid approach to answering. Like, in the early 1900's there were dire concerns about how the rising use of telephones would rapidly require an unsustainable number of switchboard operators, however this problem was rendered moot by a technological solution (automated switches). I think suggesting an alternative solution to the problem which may be feasible in the future is a reasonable answer and should be present.

OK, but to my knowledge O'Niell cylinders are not based on any engineering principles that are particularly futuristic (except for the scale of funding and logistical challenge assembly that much material) and even the logistical challenges of radiation shielding are dealt with by constructing the station in low Earth orbit and removing the windows

Genetic modifications to take the cancer out of ionizing radiation without making us into tardigrades? Maybe room-temperature superconducting transparent aluminum windows are easier?

@uhoh We already go to the dentist every year, and I don't see it as a stretch to assume that people living in space colonies will regularly visit the anti-cancer doc to have all their issues fixed. 100 years into the future is a LONG time, 100 years ago a "computer" was still a career instead of a $1 silicon IC with uncountable orders of magnitude more computational power. I don't think it's a particularly techno-optimistic stance to say "in 100 years, cancer will likely be cured or easily treatable" or "we will be able to perform radical genetic engineering", but we can agree to disagree.

We agree on most things, except that “Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.” answers aren't a good fit for most Stack Exchange sites, except perhaps World Building.

Unfortunately, cancer has proven to be one of the hard problems, in spite of the considerable incentive and resources poured into finding a cure. Too much variation, too many variables, and on top it's our own tissue (as much as we may hate it). It's a bet but I wouldn't say it's safe. (But since it's a valid possibility it's worth seeing what you can dream of with one problem solved, so no downvote from me!)
